# Can be this configuration used to faster than light communication?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, faster-than-light

I know from some popular science articles or books that is possible to make special pairs of particles which are quantum entangled. Then each of entangled particles can be moved to
different places and when one particle is "touched" it collapses to one state and second particle to exactly opposite state. As I understand this cannot be directly used to communication because it cannot be controlled to which state particle **A** collapse - its random and in result state of **B** is also random. But to know this, scientist must have method to detect collapse of particle **B**. And with this method is in principle possible faster than light communication with this or similar configuration:

Let's say we make entangled particles **A** and **B** and we also have two synchronized atomic clocks **T1** and **T2**. Then we move particle **B** together with clock **T2** for example to planet Mars and particle **A** with clocks **T1** remains on Earth, and the whole time we count seconds of both clocks.Let's assume odd number is in this second counter which will mean **YES** end even number means **NO**. Now we have established a "communication channel".

So at any later time if we "touch" particle **A** in odd second of **T1**, particle **B** will be also collapsed in odd second of **T2** and when we "touch" **A** in even second, particle **B** will be collapsed in even second (because on both places we are using synchronized atomic clocks). So having control at which time we touch particle **A** - in odd or in even second, time relative to synced clocks - we can send from Earth to Mars one bit of information without limitation of speed of light. Right?

Comment: I think the crux lies in that the observer in the frame of  A, once he/she knows the A state, knows what the B state is, but cannot communicate it to the framework of the observers of B. How will the observer at B know that A has has been measured? even or odd seconds makes no difference. B observer cannot know about the collapse of A .

Comment: @anna v: Thanks. I get it. "Touch particle" and look at particle are the same! B observer cannot look at B state without collapsing entanglement and immediatelly closing communication channel without information transfer in any direction. :-)

Comment: Isn't it the case that "when the particle 'collapses', it does not announce that. you can only tell if it has collapsed by checking it: which would, collapse it!"

Comment: @Joe Blow - yes, there is no physical sign that your particle has "collapsed" because someone measured the entangled twin, and in the many-worlds interpretation collapse doesn't even occur with measurement.

Comment: So, particles are not "connected-by" entanglement. Instead entanglement makes from two particles in some sense one particle, one point, zero dimension. Zero can be constructed as 0 = state - state or state = state. Thats entanglement. Then, observer simply cannot know state without knowing -state: If observer sees one of them separately, second one must also exist. Zero, "nonexistence" collapses to existing, separated, now independent state and -state. And yes there is nothing special about one particle compared with second one, so to be fair: which one will have + and which - is random. :-)

Comment: Would this depend upon whether the parameter you measure could be used to create a system at particle **B** dependent upon that parameter?  I ask because my graduate quantum professor seemed to argue that entanglement could be used to transmit information.  Wait, if this cannot be used to communicate, how do they perform the tests that seem to confirm this idea?  Arghh… this is why I did not focus in any quantum-dependent field…